# Should "#pragma optimize" be in header, .cpp or both?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-optimization

Should `#pragma optimize` reside in `B.h`,

```
class B{
    #pragma optimize( "", off )
    public: void f();
    #pragma optimize( "", on )
};
```

or `B.cpp`

```
#include "B.h"
#pragma optimize( "", off )
void B::f(){

}
#pragma optimize( "", on )
```

or both?

There is a useful description from the official site ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/optimize?view=vs-2019 ), but I am not sure what it means:

> The optimize pragma must appear outside a function and takes effect at
>   the first function **defined** after the pragma is seen.

What does the "defined" mean - declaration or implementation?

**Similar questions / references**

- [Why #pragma optimize("", off)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033438/why-pragma-optimize-off) - why use it.
- ["Function has no address" despite disabled optimization (/Od)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300112/function-has-no-address-despite-disabled-optimization-od) - why location matters.

Comment: What you call the implementation is also known as the definition.

Comment: @Alexander Zhang  Thank, I agree.  I tried to add in `.cpp`, but it didn't work.  Thus, I guessed I misunderstand somethings. Hmm...

Comment: To make portable code, pragmas should be prevented in general. (I admit this might be a matter of personal preference. Portable code might not be required.) However, the need of explicit controling how the compiler optimizes code appears a bit questionable to me. (I would like to know why this should be necessary. For clean code, it shouldn't.) Hence, I was quite happy to read the linked answer [SO: Why #pragma optimize(“”, off)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29033590/7478597) (which I understand that my feelings about this are not that bad).

Comment: @Scheff Is it possible to encapsulate it into some macro (to make it portable)?  I just want to use it for debugging.

Comment: The class declaration in header produces just an "interface". Actual code is produced for the implementation (aka definition) i.e. `B::f() { }` (in `B.cpp`). Without deeper knowledge I would guess that `#pragma`s are needed around the latter.

Comment: You may fiddle this out comparing (amount of) produced code for a small example on [Compiler Explorer](https://www.godbolt.org) (with vs. without the `#pragma`s). There is support for some of the newest MS VC++ compilers among others.

Comment: Btw. I believe wrongly placed `#pragma`s in the class declaration in header (in this case) just don't have any effect. (There isn't produced binary code which might be subject of (non-)optimization.) To me, it appears like switching the lamp on/off while the plug is not in the wall socket. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff  I agree with everything you said.  Thank.